# Error in using cowboy in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, cowboy

I'm using the Erlang web framework `:cowboy` in Elixir, And I got an error in `:cowboy_http_req.reply`, here is my code:

*mix.exs* is:

```
defmodule Example.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [ app: :example,
      version: "0.0.1",
      deps: deps ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  def application do
    [
      # you should start :inets and :crypto first, or it will not start cowboy
      applications: [:inets, :crypto],
      mod: {Example, []}
    ]
  end

  # Returns the list of dependencies in the format:
  # { :foobar, "0.1", git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git" }
  defp deps do
    [
      { :cowboy, github: "extend/cowboy", tag: "0.9.0" },
      # { :lager, github: "basho/lager" }
    ]
  end
end
```

*lib/example.ex* is

defmodule Example do
      use Application.Behaviour

```
  def start(_type, _args) do
    deps_started

    dispatch = :cowboy_router.compile([
      {:_, [
          {"/objects/[...]", Example.Object, []}
      ]}
    ])

    :cowboy.start_http(:http, 100, [ip: {127,0,0,1}, port: 9080], [env: [dispatch: dispatch]])

    ExampleSup.start_link
  end

  defp deps_started do
    deps = [:ranch, :cowlib, :cowboy]
    Enum.all? deps, &ensure_started/1
  end

  defp ensure_started(app) do
    case :application.start(app) do
      :ok ->
        true
      {:error, {:already_started, _app}} ->
        true
      {:error, {:not_started, dep}} ->
        true = ensure_started(dep)
        ensure_started(app)
      error ->
        IO.puts "Couldn't start #{inspect app}: #{inspect error}"
        error
    end
  end
end
```

and my *lib/example/object.ex* is:

```
defmodule Example.Object do
  @behaviour :cowboy_http_handler

  def init(_type, req, _opts) do
    {:ok, req, :undefine}
  end

  def handle(req, state) do
    {ok, req} = :cowboy_http_req.reply(200, [], "hello world", req)
    {:ok, req, state}
  end

  def terminate(_reason, _request, _state), do: :ok
end
```

I use mix to manage the reps, and I start the cowboy server with `idx -S mix`, then I send a
http stream use curl:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:9080/objects/index.html
```

and the server got error with error report:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Feb-2014::18:03:36 ===
Error in process <0.201.0> with exit value: {[{reason,undef},{mfa {'Elixir.Example.Object',handle,2}},{stacktrace,[{cowboy_http_req,reply,[200,[],<<11 bytes>>,{http_req,#Port<0.4438>,ranch_tcp,keepalive,<0.201.0>,<<3 bytes>>,'HTTP/1.1',{{127,0,0,1},58008},<<9 bytes>>,undefined,9080,<<14 bytes>>,[<<5 bytes>>],<<0 bytes>>,undefined,[],[{<<10 bytes>>,<<11 bytes>>},{<<4 bytes>>,<<14 bytes>>},{<<6 bytes>>,<<3 bytes>>}],[],undefined,[],waiting,undefined...
```

and the curl client got `500 Internal Server Error`.

**Could someone help me to finger out what's the matter? Thanks very much.**

Comment: Note: If you are on Erlang R16B02 or later, you can use application:ensure_all_started(cowboy) instead of doing it recursively yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is broken in three parts:

- reason: `undef`
- mfa: `{'Elixir.Example.Object',handle,2}`
- stacktrace: `[{cowboy_http_req,reply,[200,[],<<11 bytes>>,...]}, ...]`

In a poor way it is saying that you got `undef` error (which means undefined function) in the function `handle/2` in the `Example.Object` module. And the error has the stacktrace of calling `cowboy_http_req.reply/4`. My hunch would be that `cowboy_http_req` does not exist and you should call `cowboy_req` instead.

I would also suggest for you to [use plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug), although we don't currently have a tool for nicely showing errors, it is coming soon™. We are also shipping a logger with Elixir soon, which should help with some messages.